# Connecting a R shiny app to dropbox with httr::Oauth

Tags: r, shiny, oauth-2.0, dropbox, httr

I am trying to use Dropbox for remote storage for a R shiny app. In the good old days you used to be able to get a long-lasting token via the **rdrop2** package, but sadly that has not kept up with dropbox's migration to short-lived tokens and refresh tokens.

So, I am trying to get this done with the **Oauth_** family of functions in the **httr** package.

I know that my dropbox auth URL needs to end up looking like:
https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=APP_KEY&token_access_type=offline&response_type=code

with the `token_access_type=offline` being the important bit for attaining the refresh token

my code, so far, looks like this:

```
dropbox_endpoint <- httr::oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize",
access = "https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token")

dropbox_app <- httr::oauth_app(appname="MY APP NAME", key = "APP_KEY", 
                                       secret = "SECRET")
dropbox_token <- httr::oauth2.0_token(endpoint=dropbox_endpoint, app=dropbox_app, 
                                              cache = TRUE)
```

Where in this code do I put `token_access_type=offline` ?? I have tried a few options, but I am now just driving myself insane...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so borrowing from this post here
[How to specify user_params within httr::oauth2.0_token to obtain refresh token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71408256/how-to-specify-user-params-within-httroauth2-0-token-to-obtain-refresh-token)

`query_authorize_extra = list(token_access_type= "offline")` seems to be the ticket...I mean token

This goes in the `httr::oauth2.0_token()` function like so:

```
dropbox_token <- httr::oauth2.0_token(endpoint=dropbox_endpoint, app=dropbox_app,cache = TRUE,
query_authorize_extra = list(token_access_type= "offline"))
```